# In Next.js, unable to access the .env file using process.env.CLIENT_ID during the initial loading of Next.js

Tags: next.js, react-hooks, dotenv

I used .env file to store the sensitive data.

In .env file I stored `CLIENT_SECRET=MY_KEY`

And in a component I read the .env variable

```
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config({ path: "./.env" });
export const REDIRECT_URI = 'MY_URL';
const SignWithGoogle = () => {

    const GOOGLE_AUTH_URL = `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=${process.env.CLIENT_ID}&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}`;
    return (
        <Link href={GOOGLE_AUTH_URL}>
            <button className="w-60 p-2 rounded-md border border-black hover:bg-slate-100 transition-all ease-in-out duration-500 flex justify-center gap-3 items-center font-bold">
                <Image alt="google" src="/google.png" width={30} height={30} loading="lazy" />
                Sign with Google
            </button>
        </Link>
    )
}
export default SignWithGoogle;
```

When I visit the page, `GOOGLE_AUTH_URL` contains `undefined` at the first loading due to process.env.CLIENT_ID not loaded.

But if I refresh the page by pressing F5, then `GOOGLE_AUTH_URL` directs correct url.

This means that `dotenv` module does not work correctly and after I refresh the page, it can read and process the `GOOGLE_AUTH_URL`.

I've tried using `useEffect` hook and tried to make it as state variable, but not worked.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a specific use case that I'm not familiar with, you shouldn't need to use `dotenv` to pass env vars into your component; Next.js passes env vars to the frontend automatically, as long as you prefix the env var with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` (for example, `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_PUBLIC_VAR`).

In case you want to use the env var on the server only and not expose it to the frontend, you can omit the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` and Next.js will keep it secret. For example, `process.env.MY_SECRET_VAR` will not be exposed to the frontend, but will be available on the server (for example, in API routes and `next.config.js`).

Does it work correctly if you remove `dotenv` and add the public prefix to the env var name?

[Relevant Next.js documentation.](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables)